# Unable to dual boot Vista and Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I am trying to dual boot old Vista with new  Ubuntu 11 10. I have done many things and arrived at the point where it will boot only to a grub> prompt where it stalls. I am able to run the Ubuntu live CD  but I cannot enter Vista (as I recently could) even after a repair with the installation Vista disk. That is to say that now Windows repair does not work.

While I have never been able to dual-boot as I should on this  laptop, I was able to boot into Windows Vista while I was playing around with Easy  BCD and almost every other command I could find. The most recent and immediate thing that I did  was to use a SystemRescueCD.

http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page

that was supposed to solve all my problems.  I ran each of the various options without benefit.

I read  that wiping the entire hard drive and reinstalling Windows may not affect the boot loader.  Is it correct that there boot codes somewhere on hardware affecting the boot process that I cannot change by wiping, format,  repartitioning and installing Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get Vista bootable again and then go from there, there's a few different ways you can go about trying to fix your boot loader.  The basic process is documented here:

http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-fix-vista-mbr-repair-broken-vista/

That should be a good place to start.